# Why does the equation tag moves when using `\hspace`?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, cross-referencing, align, tags

I am using `align` environment and sometimes can see that there is an unwated space in some parts of the aligned equations. Hence, I use `\hspace` with negative length to get the desired spacing.

Even though it works well for the equation itself, the tag sometimes moves horizontally with an amount equal to the argument of `\hspace`.

Here is a sample. Before

[image]

After
[image]

The tag of some other equations seem to stay where it should be even after using `\hspace`

[image]

**This is What is the difference that made one set of equation affect the tags but the other set work well?**

Source code

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[symbolmisc]{mathastext}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
    \begin{align}
        && \frac{X_{th, kp} - X_{b}} {\chi} > \frac{X_{th, kp}} {\chi} & \implies & \frac{1}{\Theta} &> \frac{1}{\Xi} &&
        \notag
        \\
        && &
        \implies & \Theta &< \Xi &&
    \end{align}
\blindtext
    \begin{align}
        && \frac{X_{th, kp} - X_{b}} {\chi} > \frac{X_{th, kp}} {\chi} & \implies \hspace{-10mm} & \frac{1}{\Theta} &> \frac{1}{\Xi}
        \notag
        \\
        && &
        \implies \hspace{-10mm} &  \Theta &< \Xi
    \end{align}
\blindtext
    \begin{align}
        I_{sc} & = I_{sc, ref} & \hspace{-11mm} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\alpha}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \vspace{2 mm}
        \\
        V_{oc} & = V_{oc,ref} & \hspace{-11mm} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\beta}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
        \vspace{2 mm}
        \\
        P_{mp} & = P_{mp,ref} & \hspace{-11mm} \bigg[  1 + \frac{\gamma}{100} (T_{op}-T_{ref}) \biggl]
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: off topic: instead of using `\vspace{2 mm}\\ ` you can use `\\[.5em]` for example, to increase space between lines.

Comment: why are you starting each row with `&&` ?

Comment: unrelated but `\bigg[ ...\biggl]` should be  `\biggl[ ...\biggr]`

Comment: also your packages seem inconsistent you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`  but T1 encoding should only be used with (pdf)latex but fontspec requires xetex or luatex, which tex engine are you using?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative spacing was only being used to correct for space forced by the extra `&`, if the alignment is marked with a single `&` as usual then a far more natural spacing is used

[image]

I removed `fontspec` here so the example can be used with pdflatex

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
    \begin{align}
        \frac{X_{th, kp} - X_{b}} {\chi} > \frac{X_{th, kp}} {\chi} & \implies \frac{1}{\Theta} > \frac{1}{\Xi} 
        \notag
      \\
        &\implies  \Theta < \Xi
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still want to align the inequality signs precisely with each other and I think I knew how

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh if you really want that you could use `alignat` (but still you don't need `&&` at the start of every row, and do not need negative s[ace)